# Not allow selection of a certain column in a DataGridView control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have this datagridview
[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to disable the abillity of the user to select cells of the first column (the one with an arrow), but i still need the user to be able to select all other cells,exept the ones on the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the selection is moved to the target column, using the `DataGridView1.SelectionChanged` event you can prevent the selection focus,  setting the `DataGridView1.CurrentCell` to next column cell in the same row.

This works for selection events generated by both Mouse clicks and cursor movement.

```
Private blockedColumn As Integer = 0

Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = blockedColumn Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = 
            DataGridView1(blockedColumn + 1, DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

You could set `dataGridView1.Columns(0).Frozen = True` anyway, for other uses. But it's not necessary.